# Swift Enum Values With Generics

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I wanted to make a parent view model that contains some basic stuff that I want all my view models to have in SwiftUI. I'm trying to make the parent view model have a generic variables so I can inherit `ParentViewModel` in any view model I make with the custom type.

This is what I've tried and got a `Cannot find type 'T' in scope` error on the `loaded` case. Not really sure how I can make that generic, any insight here?

```
class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum Status {
        case loading
        case loaded(T)
        case error(Error)
    }
    
    @Published var status: Status = .loading
}

class ChildViewModel: ParentViewModel {
    
    init() {
        self.status = .loading
    }
    
    init(object: SomeObject) {
        self.status = .loaded(object)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a generic, you have to declare it in `<>`, which is missing in your example.

Here's a modified version that works:

```
class SomeObject { }

class ParentViewModel<T>: ObservableObject { // Declare T
    enum Status {
        case loading
        case loaded(T)
        case error(Error)
    }
    
    @Published var status: Status = .loading
}

class ChildViewModel: ParentViewModel<SomeObject> { // Specify that ParentViewModel will use SomeObject as T
    
    override init() {
        self.status = .loading
    }
    
    init(object: SomeObject) {
        self.status = .loaded(object)
    }
}
```